# How to compute class number of a torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $T$ be an algebraic torus over a number field $K$. 
Following notations in Ono's The Arithmetic of Tori, 
http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970307?sid=21105671135711&uid=3739888&uid=2&uid=3739256&uid=4

we define 
$T_A$ the adele points, $T_K$ the $K$-rational point of $T$ and 
$$T_{A,S_{\infty}}=\prod_{v \in S_{\infty}}T(K_v)\times \prod_{v \notin S_{\infty}}T_v^c $$
The class number of $T$ is defined as 
$$ h_T := [{T_A}:{T_{A,S_{\infty}}T_K}] $$
My question is how do we compute $h_T$ in pratice. If $T=\mathbb{G}_m$, $h_T$ is just the class number of $K$ and we compute it using Minkowski's bounds. But I don't know how to compute $h_T$ in general.

For an example, if $T$ is the torus $Spec(\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1))$, what is $h_T$ ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You seem to have written the class number is a ratio of two groups.  Presumably you mean the index.

Comment: @Kimball Yes that's what i mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how practical this is to compute in general, but Ono had a student, Shyr, who proved an analytic class number formula for $\mathbb Q$-tori in [his thesis](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029001954).  This can at least be used to get an expression for "relative class numbers" (quotients of class numbers).  Ono used this in [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195514771) (and maybe Shyr in his thesis also) to compute the class number of a torus which is the kernel of a norm map of a cyclic extension of Q.

Shyr's formula was later generalized by Rony Bitan (2011, Journal of Number Theory).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I will look into these papers. It seems they are very relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use relationships between different tori. For instance, your torus lives in a long exact sequence

$T\to \operatorname {Res} _{\mathbb Q(i) / \mathbb Q } \mathbb G_m  \to \mathbb G_m $

This gives you a cohomology long exact sequence:

$ H^0( \mathbb Z, \operatorname {Res} _{\mathbb Q(i) / \mathbb Q } \mathbb G_m) \to H^0( \mathbb Z, \mathbb G_m) \to H^1(\mathbb Z, T) \to H^1 ( \mathbb Z,  \operatorname {Res} _{\mathbb Q(i) / \mathbb Q }\mathbb G_m ) \to H^1(\mathbb Z, \mathbb G_m)$

Equivalently:

$ H^0( \mathbb Z[i], \mathbb G_m) \to H^0( \mathbb Z, \mathbb G_m) \to H^1(\mathbb Z, T) \to H^1 ( \mathbb Z[i], \mathbb G_m ) \to H^1(\mathbb Z, \mathbb G_m)$

Evaluating the $H^0$s as unit groups and $H^1$s as class groups:

$ \mu_4 \to \mu_2 \to H^1(\mathbb Z, T) \to 0 \to 1$

The map $\mu_4 \to \mu_2$ is the norm map, which is trivial, hence $H^1(\mathbb Z, T) = \mu_2$, and the class number is $2$.

You can probably do this in general but you need a spectral sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more about the exact sequence relates the class numbers and the unit groups ?

Comment: @raynor14 Done.

Comment: are you using etale cohomology or Galois cohomology here ?

Comment: etale cohomology.

Comment: I am confused. Then don't you need a ses of etale sheaves on $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ ? The exact sequence we have is only an exact sequence on $Spec(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Maybe it's better to call it the Weil restriction from $\mathbb Z[i]$ to $\mathbb Z$ of $\mathbb G_m$? There is a natural way to extend these group schemes to live over $\mathbb Z$ and I think the sequence remains exact.

Comment: I may have missed something, but this seems to not agree with Equation (9) in Ono's paper "A Generalization of Gauss' Theorem..." (linked in the other answer). That equation seems to say the class number is $1$ in this situation. More generally, if $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is replaced by an arbitrary imaginary quadratic field $K$, it seems like the analogous norm-one torus should have class number $2^{1-t} h_K$, where $t$ is the number of primes ramified in $K$ and $h_K$ is the class number of $K$ (at least according to Ono's paper).

Comment: @351910953 This is a fair point. The class group is the kernel of the map from integral cohomology to rational cohomology. This method only computes the integral cohomology and a correction term is needed for the rational cohomology.